# AngularJS: Using $watch in controller for the $get method of a Provider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been looking around for this but couldn't find a solution. I have a provider that simply returns RANDOM with the $get function and has another method that sets RANDOM to be a random string from an array. After setting RANDOM from config, I am able to access its current value from my config, however controllers do not detect changes to RANDOM even with $watch present. I have included my code below for your convenience.

Provider:

```
app.provider('sets', function (){
var sets= ['gogreen', 'gored', 'tekkon', 'temple', 'comehome'];
var random = sets[Math.round(Math.random() * (sets.length - 1))];
return {
    set: function () {
        random = sets[Math.round(Math.random() * (sets.length - 1))];
    },
    take: function (){
        return random
    },
    $get: function () {
        console.log("$get: " + random);
        return {
            random
        };
    }
};
});
```

I'm using this form of setup to later inject it into my config as follows. Note: I'm using UI-Router.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        url : "/{name}",
        views: {
            "canvasContainer": {
                templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
                    if (angular.isDefined(stateParams.name) && stateParams.name !== 'p' && stateParams.name !== '') {
                        return 'templates/canvas/cnv.' + stateParams.name + '.html';
                    } else {
                        setsProvider.set();
                        console.log("config: " + setsProvider.$get().random);
                        return 'templates/canvas/cnv.'+setsProvider.$get().random+'.html';
                    }

                },
                controller: 'canvasController'
            }
        }
    })
```

I have a function that reloads the current state

```
$scope.refresh = function (){
    $state.reload();
};
```

In another controller I have a $watch detecting changes on sets.random that comes from my Provider. However changes are not properly detected.

```
$scope.set= sets.random;
$scope.$watch(
    function(scope) {
        return sets.random;
    },
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("New value is: " + sets.random);
        $scope.set = newValue;
    }
    );
```

This is the output that I get in console:

```
$get: gored
$get: gogreen
config: gogreen
$get: gogreen
$watch: gored
refresh(): gored
$get: temple
config: temple
$get: temple
$watch: gored
refresh(): gored
$get: tekkon
config: tekkon
$get: tekkon
$watch: gored
refresh(): gored
$get: tekkon
config: tekkon
$get: tekkon
$watch: gored
refresh(): gored
$get: gored
config: gored
$get: gored
$watch: gored
```

refresh() and $watch are in two different controllers, but they keep spewing the same old value. So my assumption is that controllers cannot keep track of random. I'm very new to all of this and any help would be highly appreciated.

PS. My controllers are setup like this:

```
app.controller('canvasController', ['sets',  function(sets){
//-----Code----
}]);
```

Comment: The service object returned by the provider needs to broadcast on the rootScope that the value has changed, and then controllers can listen for that event. Using a watcher on the scope is not going to work, because the scope is only digested if it's parent changes. Since the service can be updated without any scope changes. The watcher won't fire.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini can you elaborate a bit more? I tried using $rootScope.$broadcast in my get method, however the entire app stops functioning after that. no errors are thrown. Also tried $injector but yielded the same result. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As Mathew mentioned, using $broadcast can be helpful however I was unable to get any results with this method as it kept throwing different errors at me. But I was able to finally get this working by messing around with the code and the solution is actually quite simple.

I modified my provider as follows:

```
app.provider('sets', function (){
    var sets= ['gogreen', 'gored', 'tekkon', 'temple', 'comehome'];
    var random;
    return {
        set: function () {
            random = sets[Math.round(Math.random() * (sets.length - 1))];
        },
        $get: function () {
            // console.log("$get: " + random);
            return {
                'random' : random,
                set : function () {
                    random = sets[Math.round(Math.random() * (sets.length - 1))];
                    return random;
                },
                get : function () {
                    return random;
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

stateProvider remained as shown in the question above.
refresh() function was modified as follows:

```
$scope.refresh = function (){
    sets.set();
    $state.reload();
};
```

and finally I didn't even need $watch or $broadcast. Value is updated on the fly in the controller as it changes in the provider.

I figured this solution out by following certain logics and patterns, but have no clue as to why it works. Any explanation would be highly appreciated as to why object retrieved directly from $get does not update in controllers automatically but if retrieved from a function within $get it does. Basically the difference between this:

```
set: function () {
            random = sets[Math.round(Math.random() * (sets.length - 1))];
        },
$get: function () {
        console.log("$get: " + random);
        return {
            random
        };
    }
```

and this:

```
set: function () {
            random = sets[Math.round(Math.random() * (sets.length - 1))];
        },
$get: function () {
            // console.log("$get: " + random);
            return {
                'random' : random,
                set : function () {
                    random = sets[Math.round(Math.random() * (sets.length - 1))];
                    return random;
                },
                get : function () {
                    return random;
                }
            };
        }
```

Thanks